# What is the difference between "bundle update" and "gem update"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I have a Ruby on Rails application and I'm using Ruby Version Manager. Can I update gems using either `bundle update` or `gem update`? Are they doing the same thing?

Comment: What is the purpose of asking and answer this question simultaneously?

Comment: Please read why it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.  That said, you'll notice I haven't accepted the answer yet, because I'm submitting the question to the community to check if it's both complete and correct.

Comment: Question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604064/rubygems-bundler-and-rvm-confusion is kinda related to this but really doesn't match the purpose of this question at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main difference is that **Rubygems** (invoked with the command `gem`) manages all the gems (gemsets if you are using RVM) for a single machine, whereas **Bundler** (`bundle`) manages a gem set for a single application (its purpose being to deploy on multiple machines).

The **Ruby Version Manager** (`rvm`) only eases the task of managing different gem versions on the same machine, but it's not application-related unless you want to name a gemset for a particular application (see [named gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics)).

Both will ignore any previously installed gems and resolve all dependencies again based on the latest versions of all gems available in the sources. However **Bundler**, unlike **Rubygems**, will only update gems and dependencies specified in the application's `Gemfile`, complying with its restrictions (version numbers and spermises).

That said, you should use `bundle install` instead of `bundle update`, to be sure you are installing the same exact gems and versions across machines.

Comment: You *should* be using version numbers (or spermies) in your Gemfile to avoid this issue.

Comment: The command name is Rubygems. The command you use to execute it is `gem`. You might want to fix that, plus, take the time to format the text so it's more readable.