# What is gem install bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, maven, npm

I know i can read it from http://bundler.io, but i have some doubts in my mind.

1. Is it like `npm for NodeJs` and `Maven for Java/J2EE`.
2. The first command i executed is `gem install bundler`. What is gem here and What is bundler, can some one enlighten me in terms of **NodeJs or Maven**.
3. Where these getting installed?. I don't specify `-g` like i do in
   NodeJs for globally.

> ```
> C:\Users\Shane>gem install bundler
> Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed bundler-1.5.3
> Parsing documentation for bundler-1.5.3
> Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.5.3
> 1 gem installed
>
> C:\Users\Shane>gem install sqlite3
> Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32
> Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32
> unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.8/sql
> tive.so, skipping
> unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.9/sql
> tive.so, skipping
> unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/2.0/sql
> tive.so, skipping
> Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32
> 1 gem installed
> ```

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604064/rubygems-bundler-and-rvm-confusion) useful. As for *Ruby*, `gem` is the *RubyGems* command, which is like *npm* for *Node*, but without `package.json` support. Therefore we use the gem *bundler* to manage our dependencies in a `Gemfile` as we would usually define in `package.json`. Then `bundle install` would be the equivalent of `npm install`.

Comment: Where is the Gemfile located? is the bundle = package.json?.

Comment: The `Gemfile` is located in the root of your *Ruby* application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have much knowledge of nodejs or java but can give you some idea.

> ### Is it like npm for NodeJs and Maven for Java/J2EE

Yes, It is *somewhat* like that `npm`.`Bundler` helps to manage application dependency like `xyz` app requires `foo` `bar` gem. `gem` is like of `libraries` which extend the app functionality. This gems are primary located in `rubygems.org` server.

> ### The first command i executed is gem install bundler. What is gem here and What is bundler, can some one enlighten me in terms of NodeJs or Maven.

when you do `gem install <gem_name>` , it creates a request to rubygems.org and download the `repo`(gem) and put it in the configured location. The location can be found in `gem env` command. To get the details of gem, you have to use `gem install <gem_name> -d` . So, when you are doing `gem install bundler`,  you are installing `bundler` gem. This `gem` will help you to resolve/manage/install application dependencies. This is like `npm install bundler` with `npm` .

### Where these getting installed?. I don't specify -g like i do in NodeJs for globally.

No, there is no need to write `-g` option here. My default, we install gems in one location which is not inside apps. personally i think transferring all those gems from one computer to another is slightly cumbersome, rather i prefer to run a command which automatically install all dependency. This is where `bundler` shines.  Let say you have an app  which requires `foo` , `bar` dependency since it uses its functionality. Without bundler, you have install this `gems` by running `gem install foo` , `gem install bar`. But with bundler, you will just do `bundle install` and you are done.

That's all. This will give you good start.

Comment: "like you install nodejs with npm" What??

Comment: @vkurchatkin , ohh sorry ..thanks.. i fixed. please review it..if it is wrong..i will delete it.

Comment: Thanks @ParitoshPiplewar, one final question: gem = libraries and bundler = npm command. We use bundler to manage all our gems.

Comment: @Shane , yes `gem = libraries` and `bundler = npm command` like `npm install express` = `gem install rails` && `npm install` = `bundle install` inside repo.. speaking generally.

Answer (score 1):

`gem install bundler` installs a gem(library) that will help you to manage your project dependencies.

Then you have a project that contains a file called `Gemfile` , when you cd into that directory and enter `bundle install` it will install all gems needed for that project.

To check where your gems are being installed take a look at the output of `gem env`.